# Hiding "Design Manager" option from Site Settings page

Tags: 2013, site-settings, design-manager, hide-elements

How to hide Design Manager option from Look and Feel section of Site settings via a feature?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and blogged about it at http://mysharepointmusings.blogspot.com/2016/01/hiding-display-manager-option-from-site.html

It took me awhile to figure this out so I'm posting here in case someone needs the answer.

Usually you can hide an option from Site Settings page by adding a feature with a custom action. In case of Display Manager, the custom action is as following:

```
   <HideCustomAction
     GroupId = "Customization"
     HideActionId = "DesignEditor"
     Id = "HideDesignEditor"
     Location = "Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings">
   </HideCustomAction>
```

`GroupId` is GroupId of the original action that added the option.

`HideActionId` is Id of the original action that added the option.

`Id` - the convention is Hide

In general, to find the ActionId and GroupId you have to search through various installed features. One easy way of doing it is to see what page is the option pointing to. In case of Display Manager link, the page is DesignSite.aspx. Doing text search for the page name in FEATURES folder pointed me to HtmlDesign\HtmlDesignProvisionedUI.xml which contained the custom action adding the option. From there you grab Id and Group Id and create the custom action to hide the original custom action as above.